# count number of sentences in a string, while accounting for decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

Assume I have a paragraph which is :

```
var word = "Hi, I am new to this world! I am a robot, my name is RX1.456 and my age is 1.0453 days. Thats all for now, you have any qeustions?"
```

I want to find the number of sentences (in this case 3) in this for which I do :

```
word = word.toLowerCase();

word.split(/[.!?]+/).filter(Boolean).length;
```

The problem is that I do not know how to handle the dot operator when it is does not mark the end of a sentence, such as decimals. How do I handle this?

Comment: periods after a sentence are always followed by a space

Comment: Would you consider `.<not-a-digit>` the end of a sentence, where `<not-a-digit>` could be a space, end of string etc?

Comment: Check the next symbol to be space or line end.

Comment: You should also trim your initial text block to ensure you're not counting trailing spaces as an additional sentence. 
word = word.toLowerCase().trim();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pherris` is right: periods after a sentence should be followed by a space.
You can modify the regex to account for it:

```
word.split(/[.!?]+\s/).filter(Boolean).length;
```

Comment: End of string is handled by `split()`: e.g. `Hi! What's up?` will split into [`Hi`,`What's up?`], giving you an array of 2 sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for something numeric:

```
word.split(/[.!?](?!\d)/g).filter(Boolean).length;
```

This will match on non-digits, whitespaces, or string endings.

Answer (score 2):

Sentences are followed by a terminating character and a whitespace character.

We can demonstrate this with JavaScript. First add references to the DOM elements through variables. In this case, we want a reference to the original paragraph, the button and the paragraph where we display our output.

With our reference to the button element, we can listen for the click event. On it, we will display the number of sentences the previous paragraph had. To do this, we want to break the sentence into an array with the `split()` function at the delimiter passed in as a parameter.

This delimiter is

```
[.?!]\s
```

This matches sentence-terminating characters, either a period, question mark or explanation mark immidiately followed by a whitespace character.

```js
var par = document.getElementById('par');
var button = document.getElementById('my-button');
var numSentences = document.getElementById('count-sentences');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  numSentences.innerHTML = par.innerHTML.split(/[.?!]\s/).length;
});
```

```html
<p id='par'>This is a sentence. is this a sentence? This is a sentence!</p>
<button id='my-button'>Count sentences</button>
<p id='count-sentences'></p>
```

Comment: This will also prevent false sentences arising from URLs in your text.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: My website is www.domain.com. I like cheese.
Two sentences, and your solution should return that correctly. Other solutions that look for digits will not.

Comment: I don't get it. I typed that in with the code I had and it returned 2. Did you misunderstand my code? I thought I said my regex was looking for sentence terminators immediately followed by a whitespace character.

Comment: I'm not communicating well. Your solution is best. 
My comment was directed at the person who posted the question, to indicate that your solution covered more than the specific case in the original example. 
Your regex handled my example. Others in this thread would not have. 
+1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

Look for sentences ending with a *white space* as well. This will help exclude numbers. Add a **terminating white space** to string to make sure the last sentence is included.

```
/[\.!\?]+\s/g
```